# Remove interrupted parts of an image for OCR python

Tags: python, ocr

I am new to image processing and want to do OCR for images with digits, however some of them are hard to be recognized, like this one:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4THZr.png)

I tried binarization but it's not effective enough, so is there any other way to remove the circle and the central star? Thanks!
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRafe.png)

output: `Shee ar`

expected output: `891972`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use tesseract an OCR engine by Google it will be so helpful in doing OCR.

Try this method for removing background

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
image_bgr = cv2.imread('images/plane_256x256.jpg')
image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
rectangle = (0, 56, 256, 150)
 Create initial mask
mask = np.zeros(image_rgb.shape[:2], np.uint8)

# Create temporary arrays used by grabCut
bgdModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)

# Run grabCut
cv2.grabCut(image_rgb, # Our image
            mask, # The Mask
            rectangle, # Our rectangle
        bgdModel, # Temporary array for background
        fgdModel, # Temporary array for background
        5, # Number of iterations
        cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT) # Initiative using our rectangle

# Create mask where sure and likely backgrounds set to 0, otherwise 1
mask_2 = np.where((mask==2) | (mask==0), 0, 1).astype('uint8')


# Multiply image with new mask to subtract background
image_rgb_nobg = image_rgb * mask_2[:, :, np.newaxis]

plt.imshow(image_rgb_nobg), plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but when applying the code for my images, it's not so effective..

Comment: I will find some other way and let you know soon